# 0x80040115 when trying to retrieve PR_DISPLAY_NAME

Tags: email, visual-c++, com, outlook, mapi

My native raw C++ program uses MAPI to traverse the tree in the Exchange Server.

Sometimes when I call `HrGetOneProp()` on a `IMAPIFolder*` pointer to retrieve `PR_DISPLAY_NAME` it fails with `HRESULT` `0x80040115`. It only happens for one particular folder, all other folders names are retrieved allright.

Outlook 2003 running on the same machine under the same user displays all folders, problematic one included.

What is the cause of the problem and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

`0x80040115` is `MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR`.  The folder could be a shared folder from another inbox, and you cannot connect to it.  Outlook may still display it properly because it cached the name somewhere.